# Is grounding necessary for a re-purposed laptop charging brick?

Tags: power-supply, audio, grounding, ground-loop

If I have re-purposed a laptop power brick, is it important to ground it or in certain use cases could one get away without earthing the power brick?

I bought a class D amplifier board off eBay which requires between 10V and 24V with sufficient power.

I got hold of an old laptop power brick from a local charity store and spliced the wires to gain access to the 18.5V and GND wires.

After wiring the board up and connecting it to my laptop using an aux cable, I got a lot of screeching as a result of a ground loop. By using tape to insulate the earth on the power brick (the one powering the aforementioned amplifier) I can silence the screeching.

The power brick says it should only be connected to a grounded outlet. I can see why it could be important for a laptop to be referenced to ground, however is it dangerous to operate the power brick in other scenarios without the earth connection? If it is very important to be connected to earth, what exactly can go wrong if one chooses to not use the ground connection?

[image: Power Brick]

Comment: Why would it be unsafe to use with a laptop while safe to use with something else?

Comment: The label "CONNECT TO GROUNDED OUTLET" makes it clear to me. SMPS do have some capacitive leakage currents.

Answer (score 2):

It is dangerous to use this without grounding, the ground protects you and the laptop in the event of a fault (short). It also lets the current go to ground and activate safety features in your house like circuit breakers or fuses. Use the ground.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule for all things, where a ground is supplied, it is supplied for a reason. This could be safety features in the product which cut power in the event of a short,EMC reasons, or (strongly related to EMC) preventing the release of ionizing radiation, such as in a microwave.

ALWAYS use an earthed socket for an earthed appliance